# How to select a method based on parameter types using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I have an array of parameters and I need to invoke an instance method that should have the most appropriate signature for the invocation, giving the number and type of parameters on my parameter array. The difficulty I'm having finding an answer for this on similar questions on StackOverflow it's because the method I'm targeting has not any specific name; instead, I must select a method from a list of methods that are decorated with a specific Attribute.

Example of a class containing some methods that can be invoked:

```
 public class TestClass
    {

        [MyAttribute]
        public void DoStuff()
        {
            // Do something
        }

        [MyAttribute]
        public void DoMoreStuff(string msg)
        {
            // Do something
        }

        [MyAttribute]
        public void DoEvenMoreStuff(string msg, int count, bool isCool = true)
        {
            // Do Something
        }

        [MyAttribute]
        public void DoEvenMoreStuff(object obj, int count, bool isCool = true)
        {
            // Do Something
        }

    }
```

Now, I need to be able to invoke one of the methods decorated with `MyAttribute`, but I don't know the name of those methods beforehand. I just need to get all the methods that are decorated with `MyAttribute` and select one of them based on an array of parameters I already have; and then invoke the selected method.

How should I do to select the best method to be invoked?

Comment: What happens when you have two parameters with the same type, how do you choose which value goes in which position?

Comment: Finding the methods with `MyAttribute` should be trivial.  What criteria other than parameter type can be applied for selection?  Is there a preference given to certain types if the evaluation identifies equally weighted methods?

Comment: Also what happens with type inheritance? For example, if you have parameters of type [string, short, bool], both of the last methods could be called.

Comment: I think what you probably want to use is `Binder.SelectMethod` on the default binder which will select the "best match" with certain kinds of implicit conversions (int to long for example). How do you intend to have the default values handled?

Comment: If there are more than one method that would be equivalent matches, an Exception is thrown. Basically, it is like an overloaded method but where the method name is not taken into consideration. The uniqueness of a method, in this case, is not based on its name but on the attribute that decorates it, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `Binder.SelectMethod` on the default binder (`Type.DefaultBinder`). This will handle standard implicit conversions (e.g. to base types, interfaces, or object) as well as some numeric conversions (e.g. int to double and long). See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.defaultbinder(v=vs.110).aspx) for a more thorough description. This will not match on optional/default parameters. So if you pass string and int it will not match the 3rd method in your example with a default value for the third boolean parameter. Note you may also want to handle the AmbiguousMatchException which is thrown when more than one candidate method could be selected. A short demonstration of its use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var methods = typeof(TestClass).GetMethods()
        .Where(mi => mi.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<MyAttribute>().Any()).ToArray();

    var flags = BindingFlags.Default; // I did not see a difference with BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding;

    Type[][] cases = {
        new Type[0],
        new[] { typeof(string) },
        new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) },
        new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(bool) },
        new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(bool) }
    };

    foreach (var typeCase in cases)
    {
        string desc = "(" + string.Join(",", typeCase.Select(t => t?.Name ?? "<null>")) + ")";

        var method = Type.DefaultBinder.SelectMethod(flags, methods, typeCase, null);

        string result = method?.ToString() ?? "No matching method found";
        Console.WriteLine($"{desc} -> {result}");
    }
}
```

Output:

> () -> Void DoStuff()
>   (String) -> Void DoMoreStuff(System.String)
>   (String,Int32) -> No matching method found
>   (String,Int32,Boolean) -> Void DoEvenMoreStuff(System.String, Int32, Boolean)
>   (Int32,Int32,Boolean) -> Void DoEvenMoreStuff(System.Object, Int32, Boolean)

Comment: Your solution works very well! And it seems like the way .NET does it by default, for what I can read on MSDN. I hope other people with the same need can find your answer useful, as it was very useful for me as well. Basically, anyone not happy with what `Type.GetMethod` does to find a method by default should find this approach very useful.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i exactly understand you, (and if i do) you are obviously aware of the **serious flaws** this approach has

However, for academic purposes only. You could do something like this

```
var argList = new object[] {"asd", 123, true };

var argTypes = argList.Select(x => x.GetType())
                           .ToList();

var testClass = new TestClass();

var method = testClass.GetType()
                      .GetMethods()
                      .Where(m => m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false)
                                              .Length > 0)
                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetParameters()
                                              .Select(y => y.ParameterType)
                                              .SequenceEqual(argTypes));

if (method != null)
{
   method.Invoke(testClass, argList);
}
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/#)

---

As stated a better approach would be to use

[Binder.SelectMethod Method (BindingFlags, MethodBase[], Type[], ParameterModifier[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.binder.selectmethod(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Selects a method from the given set of methods, based on the argument
>   type.

Comment: It sure seems `Binder.SelectMethod` is the way to go. I was not aware of Binder class. I'm trying out using it through `Type.DefaultBinder.SelectMethod`. Because `SelectMethod` accepts simply an array of `MethodBase`, I can simply get an array of methods using something like `MyType.GetType().GetMethods()
                .Where(method => !method.IsStatic
                    && method.GetCustomAttributes<ActionMethodAttribute>(true).Count() > 0);` and pass it to the `SelectMethod` along with the types of my parameters.

Comment: @ASilva agreed it seems a better approach